# iOS facebook SDK - dialog - moving buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

In my app the user can post a link to his facebook wall. However, I cannot use the "authorize" method from the SDK to login the user because it's a no go for my client that the facebook app explicitly asks for all the (basic) permissions. Therefore I immediately use a facebook dialog.

> NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>   @"http://www.google.at",  @"link",                              nil];
>
> [self.facebook dialog:@"feed"
>              andParams:params
>           andDelegate:self];

This works fine but after the login when the user can post to his wall, the publish & cancel button always moves off screen (see screenshot). When I scroll down, the button immediately moves off screen again. This does not happen after a successful login. Does anybody know how I can keep the buttons on screen? Otherwise the user is not able to post the link.

I found this solution but at least for me it does not work: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/329

[screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12018803/facebookPosting.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12018803/facebookPosting.png)

Comment: Other people are experiencing this facebook bug as well: [Bug Report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18760). I hope facebook will fix this soon.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem
and have a lot of time lost and find no solution but a workaround.

I have three methods

```
- (void) openMyFacebook
- (void) fbDidLogin
- (void) dialogFacebook
```

I call openMyFacebook

in `- (void) openMyFacebook,`
I alloc Facebook and look if there 
are already stored keys in NSUserDefaults
if not I call `[facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];`
in the delegate `- (void) fbDidLogin` I Store the Keys (same in the facbook example).
Then comes the trick.

Release facebook

```
[facebook release];
 facebook = nil;
```

and start the `- (void) openMyFacebook`
again with the stored keys.

Works perfect.

```
- (void) openMyFacebook {

    if (facebook == nil) {

        facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxxxx"];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
    }
    else {

        [self dialogFacebook];
    }

}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

//release!!!!
    [facebook release];
    facebook = nil;
//and start again
    [self openMyFacebook];
}

- (void) dialogFacebook {   

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kAppId, @"app_id",
                               linkextern, @"link",
                               facebookImageUrlString, @"picture",
                               name, @"name",

                               @" ",  @"message",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```